# Continuous vs. Discrete State-Space Model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Time-invariant continuous model:

$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)+Bu(t)$

$y(t) = Cx(t)+Du(t)$

Time-invariant discrete model:

$x_{k+1} = Ax_{k}+Bu_{k}$

$y_{k} = Cx_{k}+Du_{k}$

Why does the continuous model result in a **rate of change** $\dot{x}$, while the discrete model results in a **new state** $x_{k+1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *not* how the discretization is normally done, but see what happens if you replace the derivative by the [forward difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) for small $h>0$
$$
Ax_k+Bu_k=\dot x(kh)\approx\frac{x(kh+h)-x(kh)}{h}=\frac{x_{k+1}-x_k}{h}.
$$
Thus, the rate of change is approximately proportional to the discrete state difference, and one can write
$$
x_{k+1}\approx (Ah+I)x_k+Bhu_k.
$$